# Validating response from REST API call

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I am working on error handling a response mapping.  Before I go ahead and map the response to my domain objects, I want to validate the response. Check for errors.

I am planning to have a Validator.java class and implement validation methods for each of the API call.

Is there any alternative way in spring to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.people.net;


import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;


public class UserInfo {
    //Unicode check
    @Pattern(regexp="[0-9a-zA-Z\\s-]+", message="chars,numbers allowed only")
    String name;
    int id;

    @Pattern(regexp="([0-9]{10})", message="minLength=maxLength=10 only numbers")
    String pin;

    @Email
    String email;

    @Size(max=5, message="5 chars max")
    String emailType;
    @Size(max=5, message="5 chars max")
    String addressType;

    @Size(max=300, message="5 chars max")
    String address;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UserInfo(String name, String pin, String id) {
        super();
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public UserInfo(int id,String name, String pin, String email, String emailType, String addressType, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.email = email;
        this.emailType = emailType;
        this.addressType = addressType;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public UserInfo() {

    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEmailType() {
        return emailType;
    }
    public void setEmailType(String emailType) {
        this.emailType = emailType;
    }
    public String getAddressType() {
        return addressType;
    }
    public void setAddressType(String addressType) {
        this.addressType = addressType;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explore hibernate validator which is the reference implementation JSR-349 for bean validation. more info is here https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=349 .

Also hibernate validator is a industry standard for doing the bean validation(lots of stuff available on internet) and comes with lots of popular framework like dropwizard etc.it provide annotation based validation and allow you to write your own custom annotation based validation.

please refer on step by step guide http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-validation-example-mvc-validator, where author uses it with the spring.

Comment: Thanks for the response AmitK.  My understanding is the above validation is form validation.  What I am looking for is in a different use-case (may be the technique is same).   When I make a call to downstream from my web service, I want to validate the response from downstream.  For example, if I am calling google API, then I want to validate the response from this API.